# Visual Studio 2010 source control integration doesn't work with files outside the solution folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I have some header and cpp files that are shared between 2 projects, so I have put them in a folder named Common:

```
C:\Workspace\Common\utils.h
C:\Workspace\Common\utils.cpp
C:\Worspace\Project1\Project1.sln
C:\Worspace\Project2\Project2.sln
```

The 2 files utils.h and utils.cpp are added to both projects, and they're added to SourceSafe as well. However, "File->Source Control->Check Out" from the menu is disabled for those 2 files, even though they're added to the project.

Is this because they're outside the solution's folder, and how do I fix it? Right now I have to go and manually check out those files whenever I want to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the File -> Checkout is disabled because those files are not part of the solution. The only way to check them out from Source Control Explorer is to add them to the Solution. One way to handle this is to add a new '[Solution Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2027y2.aspx)' and add your Common Folder inside that folder. Then you should be able to do a Get Latest/Checkout from Solution Explorer.

Comment: I created the solution folder, and I added the files inside the Common Folder (using "Add Existing Item"), but they still couldn't be check out from inside VS2010.